# Cursor in jupyter notebook is a green rectangle

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I think I may have inadvertently hit some keyboard shortcut on my laptop. Each time I click inside a cell, the cursor is a green rectangle, and it seems to behave in a command mode. If I enter `a` or `i` it goes back to normal (edit mode). Which is what I want pretty much all the time, so my experience is very annoying now, each time I click inside a cell, I have to press one of those keys before being able to do anything. Restarting the jupyter server didn't help.
Anyone has an idea how I can restore defaults, i.e. go back to defaulting to edit mode?
(sorry, no screenshot because this is at my job and I am not allowed to share a screenshot. I am attaching a cursor that looks similar. Basically, instead of a simple vertical line, it's a solid green rectangle)

[image]

Comment: a and i are vi commands that allow the insertion of text.  Did you somehow enable vi edit mode?

Comment: I don't think normal jupyter-notebook has a vim mode, could you tell us if you added some kind of extensions to your jupyter-notebook application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have [jupyterlab-vim](https://github.com/jupyterlab-contrib/jupyterlab-vim) installed in you environment ( it is installed as a normal package with `pip install --upgrade jupyterlab-vim`.

in the documentation it says to use `Shift`+ `Escape` to Leave Vim Mode

or try to delete the package with `pip uninstall jupyterlab-vim`

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. This saves me a lot of headache!
For the record, this can also be toggled via Settings -> Enable notebook vim mode

Comment: I've been using Vim for about four years ... mostly because I can't get out of it.